# How to get sidekiq retry_count from inside a job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am trying to send an alert every time retry_count of a sidekiq job reaches 5(to warn an engineer to check why the worker is failing) and then continued being retried as usual.

Is there a way to get the retry count for a particular job from inside the job?

I could just use:

```
sidekiq_retry_in do |count|
  (warn engineer here)
  10 * (count + 1) # (i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40)
end
```

and send a message from in there, but I think its a bit of a hack.

Any ideas? googling didn't surface any results.

Comment: I would also benefit from having a retry count inside the job: +1 for this feature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to get the retry count from within the job, by design.

Comment: Love you work @mike any idea how to get around that?

Comment: Retry is meant to be something you perform in middleware, orthogonal to jobs.  You can fork and modify the existing RetryJobs middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Add retry middleware:

```rb
class Sidekiq::RetryMiddleware
  def call(_, job, _)
    if job['retry_count']
      job['args'].first['retry_count'] = job['retry_count']
    end
    yield
  end
end
```

Then add this middleware to the server:

```rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add(Sidekiq::RetryMiddleware)
  end
end
```

Then in ApplicationJob add retry_count:

```rb
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  attr_accessor :retry_count

  def deserialize(job_data)
    self.retry_count = job_data['retry_count'] || 0
    super
  end
end
```

Seems like that is the only way to do that. Might be better to change `executions`, but for me `retry_count` is enough.

Works with sidekiq 7.1.2